# How to write configuration file for rpm python to be installed in linux?

Tags: python, linux, rpm, setup.py

My config file 'ond.spec' is as follows:

```
%define name ond
%define version 1.0
%define unmangled_version 1.0
%define release 1

Summary: blah
Name: [ond]
Version: [1.0]
Release: [1.0]
Source0: [ond]-1.0.tar.gz
License: blah
Group: Development/Libraries
BuildRoot: <dir>
Prefix: /usr/local
BuildArch: noarch
Vendor: blah
Url: blah

%description
UNKNOWN

%prep
%setup -n [ond]-[1.0]

%build
python setup.py build

%install
python setup.py install --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files -f INSTALLED_FILES
%defattr(-,root,root)
```

Setup as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

files = ["d/*", "n/*"]

setup(name='ond',
      version='1.0',
      author='blah',
      author_email='blah',
      description=('blah'),
      license='blah',
      url='blah',
      packages = ['d', "n"],
      package_data = {'package' : files },
      classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 1 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Framework :: 'blah',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers', 
        'Operating System :: Solaris 12',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6'],
      zip_safe=False
     )
```

I did `python setup.py bdist_rpm --spec-only` in solaris, then I got the following:

```
error: Failed to execute: "rpm -q --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.src.rpm %{arch}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}.rpm\\n' --specfile 'build/bdist.solaris-2.12-i86pc/rpm/SPECS/ond.spec'
```

What is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of `rpm` do you have? And what is that command supposed to be doing? Also what's the deal with the `[word]` bits in the spec file? Is that a distutils thing?

Comment: Do not obfuscate the spec and python.py. It is quite high chance that you hide the actual error - and frankly I do not care about your projects, so no reason to hide. Second - `bdist_rpm --spec-only` only create spec file, and you already have it. So why you are trying to run it again?

Comment: Thx! It turns out that rpm is not properly installed on my machine.